# nested for loop error VBA

Tags: vba, loops, for-loop, nested

I made a nested For loop as shown:

```
For i = 1 To 14
Set curCell_a = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 6)    

If curCell_a.Value = 100 Then
Set curCell_b = curCell_a.Offset(3, -1)
cRow = curCell_b.Row     

For j = cRow To 15
Set curCell_c = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(cRow, 5)
While curCell_c.Font.Bold = False
MsgBox (curCell_c.Value)
End

Next j    
End If    
Next i
```

Yet I keep getting the error `Compile error: Next without For`

I am fairly sure I put the `Next j, End If, and Next i` in the logical order... Can someone please help me? Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is with the `End` statement: it should be `Wend` (While-End).

```
For i = 1 To 14

    Set curCell_a = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 6)

    If curCell_a.Value = 100 Then

        Set curCell_b = curCell_a.Offset(3, -1)
        cRow = curCell_b.Row

        For j = cRow To 15
            Set curCell_c = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(cRow, 5)
            While curCell_c.Font.Bold = False
                MsgBox (curCell_c.Value)
            Wend
        Next j

    End If

Next i
```

See http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/HV080557576.aspx

Answer (score 0):

A while block needs to be ended with Wend, not End. The compiler's not seeing the end of that block.